# hibernate begintransaction throwing exception

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I am a newbie to hibernate. Please let me know what is wrong in the below code ?

```
f1()
{
   try {
       s = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       tx = s.beginTransaction();
       // do some task
       tx.commit();
   } catch(Exception e) {
       tx.rollback();
       throw e;
   }
}

f2()
{
    try {
       s = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       tx = s.beginTransaction();
       f1();
       tx.commit();
   } catch(Exception e) {
       tx.rollback();
   }
}
```

The begin transaction statement in f1() throws exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nested transactions not supported.

Comment: Got it solved by creating a new session by calling openSession() rather than using current session. Thanks anyways.

Comment: just added few more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more then one `transaction (not session)` active at same time, your method is already under transaction and you don't need to create a new one; remove `s.beginTransaction();`

OR can pass same `transaction`, or else create a new one.

Concept here is - `getCurrentSession()` return same and you are calling `beginTransaction()` twice.

Comment: But there might be cases where f1() can be called/invoked directly say from front end or from another function, say f3() which has no beginTransaction(). How do we deal those cases ?

Comment: @Varun you might need to have different transaction, or pass the same one.